# Migration jboss to tomcat - javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi, jta

We are Migrating Struts 1.2 project from JDK 1.6 to 1.8 and application server jboss5.1 to tomcat 8.0. Database connection is working fine and initial pages are loading and populating some data. But when i do any action(Submit button)it throws an exception `javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance` Same code was working in jboss 5.1 but getting an error in Tomcat 8.

But i am suspecting reason for the error is UserTransaction needs to be defined separately in the context.xml but not sure about it. Please let me know.

```
UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction) myCntxt.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

If UserTransaction  needs to be defined , Please let me know how to configure in Tomcat server ?

Added database configuration in context.xml under META-INF/context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/Test1" 
   auth="Container" 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
   maxTotal="100" 
   maxIdle="30" 
   maxWaitMillis="10000" 
   username="xxxxx" 
   password="xxxxx" 
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1527:xxxx" />

<Resource name="jdbc/Test2" 
   auth="Container" 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
   maxTotal="100" 
   maxIdle="30" 
   maxWaitMillis="10000" 
   username="xxxxx" 
   password="xxxxx" 
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1527:xxxx" />
```

Added data source reference in web.xml under {project}/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>Oracle Datasource</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test1</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
   <description>Oracle Datasource</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test2</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Sample Code

```
public static void dbInit(String test1dataSourceReference,String test2dataSourceReference) throws Exception
    {

        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            tds =(DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + test1dataSourceReference);
            cds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + test2dataSourceReference);

    }
```

**Stack-trace:**

```
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:07 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:07 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:07 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:07 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:08 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:08 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:08 AM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:22 AM org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor processException
WARNING: Unhandled Exception thrown: class javax.naming.NamingException
Dec 25, 2019 7:28:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/policy] threw exception [javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance] with root cause
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:847)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.db.DbQuery.saveAppRejValue(DbQuery.java:798)
    at com.actions.PolicyAction.executeDisplay(PolicyAction.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [TomEE Comparison page](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html) indicates Tomcat does not have support for JTA (JSR 907):

[image]

You'll either need to remove the JTA code or consider another EE server like [Wildfly](https://wildfly.org/) as a simpler upgrade path.

Comment: Thank you. But I am seeing some implementation on top of tomcat to support JTA.http://jotm.objectweb.org/current/jotm/doc/howto-tomcat-jotm.html

Comment: Well JOTM hasn't had a new release in 10 years and that guide was written for Tomcat 4, also from 10 years ago.  You indicated that you're moving to Tomcat 8.0 which is also no longer supported.  You've got alot of work to get this to work with your chosen platform.  Having said that, TomEE may get you closer but, again, not with Tomcat 8.0 as that is no longer developed.

Comment: @user2848031 The comparison page stdunbar linked to comes directly from Apache. The page you linked to comes from "objectweb.org", whatever that is, and according to the HTTP headers was last modified in December 2003. On the balance of things, I think the Apache page is probably accurate when it says JTA is not supported.

Comment: @stdunbar Just would like to know what is alternative if remove JTA code and except ORM framework.

Comment: @user2848031 - as you can see from the chart even JPA isn't supported by Tomcat out of the box.  Tomcat is a *servlet only* server and you have a JEE application.  You can glue pieces onto Tomcat and you might get it to work or you could save a huge amount of time and use Wildfly, Glassfish, or TomEE.  You have JTA in your app for a reason - transaction control.  Your testing and maintenance is going to be seriously impacted by making huge application changes.  I feel that you're going down the wrong path by using Tomcat.

Comment: @stdunbar I agree Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy a 3rd party TransactionManager solution (ie Atomikos) in your Tomcat, we have done it with an older version of Tomcat. We now run Struts1 (and Struts2) app on JBoss 6, so the code is compatible with newer JBoss which provides a JTA implementation.

You can remove the transactional boundaries from your code (keeping ORM and DAO code) but I am not sure it is a great idea as data inconsistency is a risk.

If you want to minimise changes I would try to upgrade to a newer JBoss version.
A better medium-term solution is to integrate Spring Transaction Management (if you don't need to handle transactions across multiple resources).
A long-term solution would be to refactor out Struts1 (epic effort probably but I must mention it).

Good luck.

Beppe